# Changing the product name in a tag and its wiki when product name changes?

Tags: discussion, tags

We (Google) rebranded Webmaster Tools to Search Console. There is at least one [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-webmaster-tools/info) that still refers to the product by its old name.

Before I suggest an edit to the wiki, what's the guideline? Should the tag be changed or left alone until the web catches up with the new name?

Comment: For the time being, this can be added into the tag wiki. Perhaps the new name can be *added*, and (possibly later) the old one designated as a synonym?

Comment: Perhaps a moderator can rename the tag to something like [google-search-console].

Comment: Thanks guys! Following Jongware's advice, I added the new name to the tag wiki.

Comment: Hm, `google "search console"` has only 417k hits while `google "webmaster tools"` has 1470k hits. We might want to wait a bit until everyone catches up before renaming the  tag.

Comment: You man that number in Google search? That's a *very* rough estimation of the number of documents that are *potentially* retrievable for the term. I'm very surprised we actually found ~417k docs to return.